# How to check if user's ID is the same and act on the result?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Vague question, but my discord bot includes a !kick command, but I'm looking to give myself and others immunity by checking if the kick target has a specific ID tied to their user. I've checked if it's not able to read ID, and it's successfully returned the target's ID before, so I've eliminated the problem to the section where it compares ID's.

`enter code here`Code: `https://pastebin.com/uFbgzXXv`

Comment: You should enter the real code here instead of a fake `enter code here` block haha

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see with your code is your `if` statements. Multiple times you do something like this inside an `if` statement:

```
if( message.mentions.users.id === "155478460620341248" || "121733886278500354" || "138121422865301505")
    return message.channel.send("JAKE AND YUNUS ARE IMMUNE!")
```

When checking if a specific value (like `message.mentions.users.id`) is equal to multiple different strings, you have to do multiple `message.mentions.users.id === "<user id>"` statements like this:

```
if( message.mentions.users.id === "155478460620341248" ||
    message.mentions.users.id === "121733886278500354" ||
    message.mentions.users.id === "138121422865301505" )
    return message.channel.send("JAKE AND YUNUS ARE IMMUNE!");
```

You can even make this a bit nicer by doing something like this:

```
let skipUsers = [ "155478460620341248", "121733886278500354", "138121422865301505" ];
if ( skipUsers.includes(message.mentions.users.id) )
    return message.channel.send("JAKE AND YUNUS ARE IMMUNE!");
```